# Go vendor license

Tags: license-recommendation, license

I am trying to use Hyperledger Fabric open source project and it has been [licensed](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/LICENSE) under Apache License 2.0 but while check it's vendor license it got opencontainers/go-digest which is [licensed](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/vendor/github.com/opencontainers/go-digest/LICENSE.docs) under CC-BY-SA.

Is it safe to use fabric in production despite this vendor licenses ?

Comment: Yes. No. Depends - on what you require. Read the license texts and see whether you can and do abide by them.

Comment: I can do abide the rules of the project I am using, but should i care for the dependent license also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the opencontainers/go-digest part of the repository has 2 license files, LICENSE.code and LICENSE.docs. Based on the file extensions, one appears to contain the license for the source code and the other for the documentation.

The .go files themselves and the LICENSE.code file all refer to the Apache 2.0 license as being applicable. It appears that the documentation has been stripped from this copy of opencontainers/go-digest, so the LICENSE.docs can be ignored.

TL/DR: Yes, it is safe to use fabric in a closed-source project. The CC-BY-SA license you found in the vendor section does not actually apply to any portion of the code.